# Beamer animation fails to show first frame of animation when "poster" is included in \movie call

Tags: beamer, animations, multimedia

This is a follow up question on SE413129. Including movies in a beamer frame with the option "poster", as described on page 134 of the beamer guide does not result in frame 1 being shown. Some (unpredictable) frame is shown.  Once the poster is clicked the animations plays as expected.  A MWE developed under Debian Buster:

The following Octave script makes a sequence of images that show the frame number for each of 100 frames:

```
set(gcf,"position",[20,100,800,450]);
for kt=1:100
  clf
  text(0.,0.,strcat(int2str(kt)));
  axis([-1 1 -1 1])
  drawnow
  fname=strcat('./jpg/img',num2str(kt,"%04i"),'.jpg');
  eval(['print -djpeg "-S800,450" ' fname]);
end
```

The images are stitched together into an animation with

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%04d.jpg -r 24  anim.mov
```

The animation can be viewed with ffplay anim.mov

A minimal beamer presentation is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Singapore}  % name of theme substituted here
\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\begin{document}
%% example frame with animation
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Numbers}
\movie[height = 0.6 \textwidth,width = 1.0\textwidth,poster]{}{anim.mov}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is compiled with

```
pdflatex anim.tex
```

When the resulting pdf is displayed (with okular or evince) the displayed frame is never frame 1, but some other frame.  Once the displayed frame is clicked, the animations (starting with frame 1) runs as it should.

Comment: Can you try to explicitly set the correct image? `\movie[height = 0.6 \textwidth,width = 1.0\textwidth,poster]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img1}}{anim.mov}` (or whatever the name of your first image is)

Comment: @samcarter I replaced the "movie" line in the MWE with: \movie[height = 0.6 \textwidth,width = 1.0\textwidth,poster]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img0001.jpg}}{anim.mov}.  I have verified that img0001.jpg does have the number 1 in the center of the image.  However anim.pdf still shows the animation frame with number 3 or 4, as before

Comment: can you make the movie and the images available somewhere?

Comment: @samcarter   I have uploaded the images and anim.mov onto my dropbox directory, my dropbox uname is clinton.winant@gmail.com, the files are in a directory called Beamer.  I cant thank you enough for sticking through this with me.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to your dropbox folder (I don't use it myself, so I have no idea how to find something based on your user name)

Comment: Another quick idea: `\movie[height = 0.6 \textwidth,width = 1.0\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img1}}{anim.mov}` (without `poster`)

Comment: @samcarter I am no better at dropbox than you, it seems that to invite you I need an email address, and you may well not want to share that.  I tried your latest suggestions, and it works after a fashion:  I do get the proper image, and the animation does start up.  However there is an annoying feature: a blacked out screen appears briefly between the click and the animation, that does not happen when the "poster" option is included.  If you want to cast your latest suggestion as an answer, I can accept it.  BTW do you know of another site for sharing files?

Comment: As far as I know, there should be some possibility in dropbox to share a specific file by creating a special link to it.

Comment: @samcarter  Got this: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/23vy8xe322knmxo/AAA6iq6nkWzyQZetM41_sNnAa?dl=0

Comment: @ Clinton Winant Thanks! I will try tomorrow - currently I only have a bad internet connection.

Comment: The best I could come up with is a white screen, please see my edited answer

Comment: Off-topic: for such images with lines, png is much better suited than jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76912/discussion-between-clinton-winant-and-samcarter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you could manually set the image which should be shown as preview by using

```
\movie[height = 0.6 \textwidth,width = 1.0\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img1}}{anim.mov}
```

(replace `img1` with the name of the first image)

Drawback: as learned from the comment of [Clinton Winant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429427/beamer-animation-fails-to-show-first-frame-of-animation-when-poster-is-include?noredirect=1#comment1075543_429427) a short black screen is visible between the click and the start of the movie

---

As an alternative to the black screen, you could use `media9` package - this shows a white screen :)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{media9}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Singapore}  % name of theme substituted here
\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\begin{document}
%% example frame with animation
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Numbers}
%\movie[height = 0.6 \textwidth,width = 1.0\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img0001}}{anim.mov}



\includemedia[
  width=\linewidth,
  totalheight=0.6 \textwidth,
%  activate=pageopen,
  passcontext,  %show VPlayer's right-click menu
  addresource=anim.mov,
  flashvars={
    %important: same path as in `addresource'
    source=anim.mov
  }
]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img0001}}{VPlayer.swf}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```